# Eignevalues of $A+tI$ knowing eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question: If $A$ is a square matrix and t is a real number, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda+t$ is an eigenvalue of $A+tI$. (Here $I$ is the identity matrix.)

I am not sure how to prove this matrix.

Comment: What is your definition of eigenvalue?

Comment: $Av=\lambda v\implies (A+tI)v=????$

Comment: In your last sentence : one does not prove a matrix, one proves a result.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
\begin{aligned}
Av &= \lambda v \\
\iff Av + tv &= \lambda v + t v \\
\iff (A + tI) v &= (\lambda + t) v
\end{aligned}
This means that $v$ an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ implies that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A + tI$ with eigenvalue $\lambda + t$. Similarly, the converse holds by working from the bottom line up in the above.